# Produce volatility smile/skew with G2++ model

Tags: volatility-smile, short-rate, volatility-skew

Suppose I have a G2++ short rate model:
$$r(t)=x(t)+y(t)+\phi(t), \quad r(0)=r_0$$
with
$$dx(t)=-ax(t)dt+\sigma dW_1(t), \quad x(0)=0$$
$$dy(t)=-bx(t)dt+\eta dW_2(t), \quad y(0)=0$$
$$d\langle W_1,W_2\rangle_t = \rho dt$$
Although it has many features that are typical stylized facts of the yield curve, the does not seem to capture well the volatility smile/skew. I would like to know whether there are some model extensions enabling to partly capture the smile/skew, without switching to a different model, such as Cheyette, SABR or ZABR.